# Inversing alpha and distance?

Tags: mapping, processing, alpha

I am looking to set a certain object's alpha to fade in relation to its distance.

These values changes over time.

The range for distance is 0 to 51.
The range for alpha is 0 to 255.

I start by using the map function:

```java
   alpha = map(d,0,51,0,255);
```

Now, if the value of d is, for example '16', the alpha value is '80'.

The extremes of this would be if distance at '0', alpha is '0' and distance is '51', alpha is '255'.

What I'm looking to achieve is to inverse the relationship, wherby a distance value of 51 will result in a output alpha of '0' instead.

I have tried using the standard y=k/x formula but something's messing with my head and I cannot get it to work alongside the mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just subtract it from `255`?

```java
alpha = 255 - map(d,0,51,255,0);
```

Now if the original value was `255`, the new value is `0`. If the original value was `0`, the new value is `255`.

You could also subtract the distance from `51`.

If this doesn't do exactly what you want, then I suggest making a chart of the old values vs the new values you want. Do you notice a pattern you can apply in the code?

Comment: Sorry, i forgot the mention the values are to change over time as the objects interact with each other.

Comment: @user4985 Yeah, that's fine. The value will change anytime the value of `d` changes. This is just inversing the number you get each step.